# Выполнять действия при наведении курсора мыши на QPushButton PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, hover, qpushbutton

Я взяла код анимации кнопки при наведении на неё курсора мыши из [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089882/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-hover-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-qpushbutton-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-qgraphicsdropsha). В отдельном проекте с созданием данной кнопки всё работает, но я не могу разобраться, как сделать то же самое, но с уже созданной в *Qt Designer* кнопкой.

Обработка наведения создаётся с помощью этого класса.

```
class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
    pass

def enterEvent(self, event):
    self.hover.emit("enterEvent")

def leaveEvent(self, event):
    self.hover.emit("leaveEvent")
```

Моя попытка сделать это с уже готовой кнопкой:

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QApplication, QMainWindow


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        pass

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("enterEvent")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("leaveEvent")


class AnimationShadowEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect):

    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimationShadowEffect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColor(color)
        self.setOffset(0, 0)
        self.setBlurRadius(0)
        self._radius = 0
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setTargetObject(self)
        self.animation.setDuration(1500)            # Время одного цикла
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)             # Постоянный цикл
        self.animation.setPropertyName(b'radius')
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.5, 15)

    def start(self):
        self.animation.start()

    def stop(self, r=0):
        # Остановить анимацию и изменить значение радиуса
        self.animation.stop()
        self.radius = r

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, r):
        self._radius = r
        self.setBlurRadius(r)


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("Test.ui", self)

        #Инифицализация анимации
        self.aniButton = AnimationShadowEffect(QtCore.Qt.white, self.designer_button)
        self.designer_button.setGraphicsEffect(self.aniButton)

        #Добавление эффекта к кнопке
        self.designer_button = PushButton(self.designer_button)
        self.designer_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.designer_button.hover.connect(self.button_hover)


    def button_hover(self, hover):
        if hover == "enterEvent":
            self.aniButton.start()
        elif hover == "leaveEvent":
            self.aniButton.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Test.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <widget name="__qt_fake_top_level">
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="designer_button">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>80</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>201</width>
     <height>71</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 42);
    border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
    display: block;
    font-family: Calibre, Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida          Grande sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

QPushButton:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(16, 16, 24);
    color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
}

QPushButton:pressed { 
    background-color: rgb(6, 6, 8);
    color: rgb(41, 41, 62);
}

</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
</ui
```

---

Также залила этот файл на [мегу](https://mega.dp.ua/ru/xePw), чтобы сразу можно было использовать его.

Результат выполнения данного кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** Также я пробовала способ из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508552/pyqt-mouse-hovering-on-a-qpushbutton), он также работает, но с его помощью можно отследить только наведение курсора, то есть анимация происходит, но при наведении курсора в другое место, она не пропадает.

Снизу демонстрация того, что мне нужно. Только мне нужно это сделать с кнопкой в подгружаемом файле **`UI`**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте свой пример, который можно воспроизвести и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick добавила видео в вопрос, полный пример сейчас скину.

Comment: @S.Nick добавила в вопрос полный код, так создаётся ещё одна кнопка в кнопке, но эффект работает. Вопрос в том, как сделать то же самое, но без создания ещё одной кнопки?

Comment: вы забыли добавить `Test.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick точно... Уже исправила, добавила код и залила UI файл на мегу.

Comment: @S.Nick вы сможете помочь?

Comment: да, подождите пару минут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Опубликованный `.ui` битый и отличается от того что по ссылке.

Что я сделал:

- `pyuic5 Test.ui -o Test_ui.py -x`
- внес изменения в `Test_ui.py`:

1. Добавил `class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton): ...`
2. Добавил строку `self.designer_button = PushButton(self.centralwidget)`
3. Убрал сроку `display: block;`

- Внес изменения в `main.py`:

1. Добавил `from Test_ui import Ui_MainWindow`
2. Поменял `class AnimationShadowEffect ...` , потому что в вашем что-то было не так.
3. Смотрите строку `class App(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):`
4. Смотрите строку `self.setupUi(self)`

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QApplication, QMainWindow

from Test_ui import Ui_MainWindow                                               # +++


class AnimationShadowEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect):                         # Поменял !!!
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimationShadowEffect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColor(color)
        self.setOffset(0, 0)
        self.setBlurRadius(0)
        self._radius = 0
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setTargetObject(self)
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)            # Время одного цикла
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)             # Постоянный цикл
        self.animation.setPropertyName(b'radius')
        # Вставить значение
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0, 1)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.5, 30)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(1, 1)

    def start(self):
        self.animation.start()

    def stop(self, r=0):
        # Остановить анимацию и изменить значение радиуса
        self.animation.stop()
        self.radius = r

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, r):
        self._radius = r
        self.setBlurRadius(r)
        

class App(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                                  # +++ Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
#        uic.loadUi("Test_.ui", self)
        self.setupUi(self)                                              # +++

        self.designer_button.setCheckable(True)
        #Инифицализация анимации
        self.aniButton = AnimationShadowEffect(QtCore.Qt.white, self.designer_button)
        self.designer_button.hover.connect(self.button_hover)   
        self.designer_button.setGraphicsEffect(self.aniButton)

    def button_hover(self, hover):
        if hover == "enterEvent":
            self.aniButton.start()
        elif hover == "leaveEvent":
            self.aniButton.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Test_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        pass

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("enterEvent")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("leaveEvent")


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(357, 205)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(41, 41, 62);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
#        self.designer_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.designer_button = PushButton(self.centralwidget)              #  PushButton      
        
        self.designer_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 201, 71))
        self.designer_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 42);\n"
"    border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);\n"
"    border-radius: 15px;\n"
"    color: rgb(202, 202, 202);\n"

" /*   display: block;                                                     ЭТО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ !!!*/     \n"

"    font-family: Calibre, Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida           Grande sans-serif;\n"
"    font-size: 16px;\n"
"    font-weight: 500;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover { \n"
"    background-color: rgb(16, 16, 24);\n"
"    color: rgb(76, 76, 76);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed { \n"
"    background-color: rgb(6, 6, 8);\n"
"    color: rgb(41, 41, 62);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.designer_button.setObjectName("designer_button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 357, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.designer_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Есть ещё вопрос: если у меня интерфейс в формате `.ui`, то мне нужно конвертировать его в `.py` и менять инициализацию всех кнопок? С файлом `.ui` это невозможно сделать как я поняла?

Все возможно.

1. Создаете собственный виджет, например `PushButton`, который наследуется от `QPushButton` ->
   (`my_PushButton.py`)
2. В Qt Designer заменяем `QPushButton` на `PushButton`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Все, запускаем `main.py`

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QApplication, QMainWindow
#from Test_ui import Ui_MainWindow          


class AnimationShadowEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimationShadowEffect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColor(color)
        self.setOffset(0, 0)
        self.setBlurRadius(0)
        self._radius = 0
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setTargetObject(self)
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)            # Время одного цикла
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)             # Постоянный цикл
        self.animation.setPropertyName(b'radius')
        # Вставить значение
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0, 1)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.5, 30)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(1, 1)

    def start(self):
        self.animation.start()

    def stop(self, r=0):
        # Остановить анимацию и изменить значение радиуса
        self.animation.stop()
        self.radius = r

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, r):
        self._radius = r
        self.setBlurRadius(r)
        

class App(QMainWindow):                    #, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("Test_333.ui", self)                                  # +++
#        self.setupUi(self)         

        self.designer_button.setCheckable(True)
        #Инифицализация анимации
        self.aniButton = AnimationShadowEffect(QtCore.Qt.white, self.designer_button)
        self.designer_button.hover.connect(self.button_hover)   
        self.designer_button.setGraphicsEffect(self.aniButton)

    def button_hover(self, hover):
        if hover == "enterEvent":
            self.aniButton.start()
        elif hover == "leaveEvent":
            self.aniButton.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**my_PushButton.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        pass

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("enterEvent")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("leaveEvent")
```

**Test_333.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>357</width>
    <height>205</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(41, 41, 62);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="PushButton" name="designer_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 42);
    border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
    font-family: Calibre, Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida          Grande sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

QPushButton:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(16, 16, 24);
    color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
}

QPushButton:pressed { 
    background-color: rgb(6, 6, 8);
    color: rgb(41, 41, 62);
}

</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>357</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PushButton</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>my_PushButton</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Есть ещё вопрос: если у меня интерфейс в формате .ui, то мне нужно конвертировать его в py и менять инициализацию всех кнопок? С файлом .ui это невозможно сделать как я поняла?

Comment: @Афродита я добавил для вас и другое решение.

Comment: спасибо большое, очень помогли. Я думаю этот вопрос будет полезным другим, так как при поиске по гуглу мне ничего нужного не удалось найти, а тут решения даже несколькими способами.

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо! Мне это тоже помогло.
Как раз искал что то подобное.
Есть один нюанс. Все работает в pycharm, но после конвертации проекта в .exe Проект не запускается в введу отсутствия нужно файла. Я думаю дело в my_PushButton.py нужно его как-то подгрузить что-ли. Без него все было хорошо.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/715204)