# Кастомизация кнопки

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt5

Решил сделать красивую кнопку с помощью PyQt5 и CSS.

Начал делать сам, но результат не понравился. Нашел пару сайтов ( https://codepen.io/caraujo/pen/VYOjNM и https://codepen.io/thejamespower/pen/OVNYLL ).

Не как не могу изменить вид кнопки на те которые хочу, так как выскакивают ошибки ( например ***Could not parse stylesheet of object QPushButton(0x21f7f28f590, name = "pushButton"*** ).

Из первого сайта ( https://codepen.io/caraujo/pen/VYOjNM ) я хотел был взять кнопку ***Burn***. Она имеет эффект свечения надписи при наведении курсора  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из второго сайта ( https://codepen.io/thejamespower/pen/OVNYLL ) - кнопку  ***Skew Fill Left -> Right***. Она имеет анимацию заполнения кнопки слева направо при наведении курсора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(800, 595)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        Form.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 480, 191, 61))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(pushButton_StyleSheet)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        

 
        

pushButton_StyleSheet = '''
#pushButton {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #78a4e8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  
}

#pushButton:hover {background-color: #4483e4;}

#pushButton:pressed {
  background-color: #686c73;

}

'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать вместо `pushButton {} ` написать `QPushButton {} `

Comment: Gidra постарайтесь как-то лучше объяснить и показать какую красивую кнопку вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick мне ещё надо что-то добавить в вопрос? Если дано, постараюсь добавить что-то ещё

Comment: Gidra  посмотрите может вам такое подойдет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089882 или  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227192/

Comment: Gidra может быть такая реализация будет полезна для вас   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360863/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-qpushbutton-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-css/1360998#1360998